# Should the Vyankatesh Stotra (Marathi) be read at midnight?

Tags: stotra, venkateshwara

As per the translation of the Vyankatesh Stotra that I came across online (blog) it must be read at midnight to fulfill wishes. Can someone who understands Marathi please confirm how an anushthan for a particular wish must be completed as per the instructions in the stotra?

https://www.bhaktiras.net/shri-vyankatesh-stotra/

Comment: In the Midnight to see "pratyaksha" lord vyankatesh, and thus any wish gets fullfiled. However it's not necessary, even reciting everyday is enough. I will answer by evening....or someone else might...

Comment: @Proxy- According to that blog I read, it said we need to recite it for 1 mandala (which I am assuming is 40-48 days, not sure) to fulfill a wish and do the sankalpa at midnight. Please clarify. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place where the "midnight" is referred is:

> देवीदास विनवी श्रोतया चतुरा | **प्रार्थनाशतक पठण करा | जावया मोक्षाचिया मंदिरा |** काही न लागती सायास || १०६ ||

> एकाग्रचित्ते एकांती | **अनुष्ठान कीजे मध्यराती** | बैसोनिया स्वस्थचित्ती | प्रत्यक्ष मूर्ति प्रकटेल || १०७ ||

Saint Devidas requests the listener, to complete the (*प्रार्थनाशतक*) i.e. The 100th recitation of the stotra. But where?, (*मोक्षाचिया मंदिरा*) a place where there is calmness, typically place without anyone, your home, temple etc. (When?) (*अनुष्ठान कीजे मध्यराती*) I.e. one needs to do this in middle of night, with calmness and devotion. But What happens after that?, (*प्रत्यक्ष मूर्ति प्रकटेल*) i.e. He himself, lord Venkatesh will appear.

In the middle of night complete 3 chants & continue this for 32 days. Finally on 33rd day chant it 4 times. This completes the 100th recitation in interval of 33 days. The more conditions you put, the better it is. This must be performed by taking a bath, and keeping the cloths wet.

However for fullfilment of wishes its little different. It is stated in the following verses:

> इच्छा धरुनी करील पठण | त्याचे सांगतो मी प्रमाण | सर्व कामनेसी साधन | पठण **एक मंडळ** || ९२ ||

> By holding a wish in mind, the one who reads it must do it for one mandala.

> पुत्रार्थियाने तीन मास | धनार्थियाने एकवीस दिवस | कन्यार्थियाने षण्मास | ग्रंथ आदरे वाचवा || ९३ ||

> Recite this, to get a son for 3 months, 21 days for money, and 6 months for a Girl child.

> क्षय अपस्मार कुष्ठादिरोग | इत्यादि साधने प्रयोग | त्यासी एक मंडळ सांग | पठणे करुनी कार्यसिद्धी || ९४ ||

> To get relief from diseases and many other things. He will succeed by reciting for 1 Mandala.

I.e. To get money he must do it for 21 days, to get a male child for 3 months and to get a female child for 6 months. For all other things for 1 mandala which is 42 days. However there is much debate on exactly how many chants one need to do per day, *few prescribe 21 chants per day*, *few say 12* times, either starting from morning or spreading it across the day. *Few say at least 3 chants per day*.

Thus to fulfill wishes it is not in the middle of night, as number of days become important. However if you wish you can recite it at night as the benifits become stronger.

*If this cant be done, **one can read it at least one time everyday**.

<sub>[This](http://prabodhankar.org/node/247/page/0/77) mentions a incident where the person was chanting it in the morning for about seven hours starting from 4 a.m. to get fulfilled by money</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. This is amazingly helpful! Lots of gratitude to you.